# Is it necessary to use a database in my case?

Tags: database, for-loop, arraylist, android-sqlite

I've made a quiz app and it's working fine.
I have used an `ArrayList` to 'store' all the questions I made up myself. Right now it contains 60 questions. I eventually want to expand this to ~300 questions. It looks like this right now:

```
questions = new ArrayList<>();
Question question0 = new Question(R.drawable.piano, "Welke coureur verkoos een carrière als coureur boven een carrière als pianist?", "Max Verstappen", "Fernando Alonso", "Jean Alesi", "Adrian Sutil", 3);
questions.add(question0);
```

And I have done this 60 times now. At first I thought I could use a for-loop to add all the questions like :

```
for (int i=0; i<questions.size(); i++){ 
questions.add(i);
}
```

But this is not possible, because the size of the questions is still 0 in the beginning. Now I have a lot of the same code, and I was wondering how to solve it. I could use a database, but I still have to create colums/rows and have to add all the questions. Which takes even more time, right?

I would like to get some advice on what to use and why.

Thanks.

Comment: Just add a "new Question (...)" to the list. But even then, even just parsing a file resource would make things much easier. Is a DB *necessary*? No, but it might be *better*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use a database in my case?

No. However, depending upon what you want from the quiz, a database may be the way to go. If you are just going to present a quiz, the same quiz with the same questions and answers then the App may then no need.

However, if you ventured into storing results, displaying a subset of the questions (e.g. those not attempted or those not answered correctly etc) then you are moving into the realms of the database being desirable perhaps even needed.

> I could use a database, but I still have to create colums/rows and have to add all the questions.

Rows would be created by adding the questions.

> Which takes even more time, right?

Perhaps not with one of the available SQLite tools, the database could be created using such a tool and then copied into the App (typically as an asset) (more work to implement copying the asset). Of course should the App develop then this could save time (if implemented well).